# Is Deuce an Atheist?

Tags: rock, rap

Deuce, from Nine Lives, wrote a song called [America](https://www.google.com/search?q=america+by+deuce&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS895US895&oq=america+by+deuce&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l4.8303j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It has the following lyrics:

> They wanna see blood,
> They wanna see hate,
> Like needle in your vain,
> Sickness with no name,
> In a world that's insane,
> Was America to blame?
> When you're prayin' for a change,
> To a god with no face!

Maybe "when you're prayin' for a change, To a god with no face!" means that the people are basically praying to nothing?

> 'Cause of I've got one religion
> And I've got one decision it's a big fuck you!

I'm not so sure about this, but I'm pretty sure it means that his religion and decision is "a big  fuck you!"

> Eenie-meenie-minie-mo,
> Aach one is gonna know when your time is coming soon,
> 'Cause there ain't enough of room in this world for us two.
> Yeah I hate to break the news,
> But I'll break it in this music to let world know who.
> Who you've been using, who you're abusing,
> It's the suits you've been fooling but you know that you're useless.
> So he's acting so ruthless, deep inside you're just ruined,
> 'Cause I just keep on moving to show you the truth bitch.

This sounds like something atheists tend to talk about, or feel.

As an atheist, this song felt like it hit a chord in me.

So is Deuce an atheist?

Comment: Based on what I've heard of him (he was a favorite of mine at one point), he's **definitely** not religious. Unless he recently converted, that is. **Very** recently.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Do you have a place that I could look at though? Because I do believe he at least isn't religious (I don't know if he's an atheist), but I just want to know. Also, I just want to find someone like me, another atheist, who is a popular singer.

Comment: @MicahWindsor Lol true